# Obsolete java applets

Tags: java, web-applications, applet

So this year I found out that when compiling a java applet in Eclipse Oxygen that java applets are about to be obsolete. Is Oracle going to release a new API that allows applets in websites? If not, what are the alternatives and what are their advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Oracle going to release a new API that allows applets in websites?

No. They are accepting the decision of browser manufacturers to remove all plug-ins from their rendering of web pages. See [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web) for more info.

> If not, what are the alternatives ..

HTML 5 and JS can replace the vast majority of the reasons people ever used applets.

> .. and what are their advantages and disadvantages?

The primary advantage of JS / HTML is that - it is supported in modern browsers. It also helps keep the web page a keyboard navigable thin client.